# Vimscript :execute command passing numeric prefix

Tags: vim

If I type `5/something` vim will search the fifth ocurrence of "something".
But `execute '5/something'` will interpret the 5 as part of the pattern and start searching from line 5, as if I had typed `:5/something`. That's fine, but now: is it possible to invoke `execute` somehow in order to get the `5/something` behavior? I know I could just repeat the search 5 times in this particular example; the question is not how to get the same effect but, in general, if `execute` could be used to pass a prefix argument to the target command.

Answer (score 1):

#### Normal vs Command-line Mode

`5/foo` is quite different from `:5/foo`. When you use `:execute` you can kind of imagine your command starting with a `:`. e.g. `execute foo` would become `:foo`. This means `:5/foo` is a range.

#### Ranges

Often ranges are applied to ex-commands. e.g. `:%s/foo/bar`, `:'<,'>left`, or `:11-35g/foo/normal 3x`. However you can execute just a range which will move the cursor to that position. Some people (like me) use `:{line-number}` instead of `{line-number}G` to jump to a specific line.

Ranges can take more than numbers. They can take marks and searches and can be combined. Lets take `:5/foo` for example:

- `:5` jump to the 5th line
- `/foo` go to the next line containing `foo`

#### Repeating an ex-command

There are many ways:

- Use `@:` to execute the last command-line `[count]` times.
- Use a loop! e.g. `for i in range(5) | execute 'foo' | endfor`
- If you are executing on lines then use `:g`. e.g. `:g/foo/...`
- Use a macro

Or create a custom command to help you out:

command! -count=1 -nargs=+ -complete=command RepeatEexecute for i in range() |  | endfor

#### For more help see

```
:h range
:h :execute
:h /
:h @:
:h :for
:h :g
:h q
:h :command
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand all that, I'm not saying `:execute` does the wrong thing in my example but asking for a way to programatically execute a command with a number prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is to execute `:normal` in the argument to `:exe` and embed/concatenate the prefix at the start of the argument to `:normal`. For example:

```
:exe 'normal 5/something^M'
```

where the `^M` is a literal carriage return character. (There are 16 ways I'm aware of that this can be typed:

1. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^M</kbd>
3. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
4. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>
5. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
6. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
7. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
8. <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>S-Enter</kbd> (Works on most vims, but sends NUL in Cygwin mintty, and sends literal `<S-CR>` in Win32 CLI/GUI and Mac OS X GUI command-line mode.)

Plus 8 more that are the same as the above 8, but with <kbd>^Q</kbd> instead of <kbd>^V</kbd>. Assumes no remappings, and stty -ixon in Unix-like CLIs to allow <kbd>^Q</kbd> to get through. Hexadecimal letters are case-insensitive.) You could also do

```
:exe 'normal 5/something'.nr2char(13)
```

Now, if you want to depend on an interactive count, say, carried forward from a mapping invocation, then you can concatenate `v:count1` as the prefix:

```
nnoremap \t1 :<C-u>exe 'normal '.v:count1.'/something'.nr2char(13)<CR>
```

Functionally identical alternative:

```
nnoremap \t1 :<C-u>exe 'normal <C-r>=v:count1<CR>/something'.nr2char(13)<CR>
```

Now typing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> will search forward for the first occurrence of `something`, and <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> will search forward for the fifth occurrence of `something`.